# SVG disappears in firefox on URL change (jquery.history.js)

Tags: jquery, firefox, svg, history.js

In [www.xc-tournament.com/tournament/10](http://www.xc-tournament.com/tournament/10) you can see a paddle-tennis league. The hexagons near participants names are `svg` with a filled background (there will be the app users profile image).

When the user click on any of left column options: *Clasificación* (classification), *Primera Jornada* (first round) or *Información* (information), or when the user clicks on *Siguiente* (next) or *Anterior* (previous), the operational sequence is:

- `window.History.pushState(...)` with the new url
- if the content must be loaded from server (not the case)

  - make an AJAX call to load it
- else

  - `hide` the main component (via jQuery)
  - `show` the selected one

The problem is that on this operation and **only in Firefox** (different versions and OS) the `svg` hexagons disappear in some places as the left column or the classification table. The DOM objects are not altered nor I find any clue about why aren't they shown.

As I said, no new content is loaded just hidden or showed with jQuery and the url is changed to mantain navigation.

¿Is this a bug in Firefox? ¿Is there any way to avoid it?

Comment: Please try and reproduce this behaviour in a smaller example, and post it to jsfiddle.net or similar.  Posting links to a live site is undesirable because (a) it makes it hard to debug, and (b) when you ultimately fix it, this question will probably not be helpful to other people later.

Comment: Hardly I can post it in jsfiddle while navigation issues are affected. If the issue is fixed a complete explanation can make it helpful enough.

Comment: This is a [known bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=652991).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have xml:base set. pushState affects this and means that your URL changes. To work around this use absolute rather than relative URLs in your fill attributes.

Firefox is working correctly per the various specifications but that isn't terribly useful and we think the specifications should change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I've not `xml:base` set and I've already tried with absolute URLs (there are absolute URLs at this moment).

Comment: You are **not** using absolute URLs at the moment. fill="url(#c9yZlF8ETJufMfuu3K)" is relative you'd need to use the complete path instead.

Comment: I've try to use absolute URLs in fill attribute (I thought that the absolute URL should be the one in pattern definition). The problem seems to be that when the paremeters (not their values) in the page URL changes with `pushState` it's interpreted as an URL change and absolute references doesn't work.

Comment: @francadaval In fact, this is a Firefox bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=652991

Comment: @Buzinas sort of, Firefox implemented the specification, people complained that they had problems, we worked with the specification people to change the specification and we're now updating Firefox to the newly agreed specification.